# Php: Saving Server resources - theoretical

Tags: sql, laravel, foreach, resources

(Use Laravel)
I have saved rows in my table. On updating, if I uncheck checkbox, the value must be reset to default. So my checkbox receives only checked values and I take all rows from database and set them to default first, then I set the needed value only for checked rows. This is done in 2 rows of code,

```
\DB::table('tablename')->where('val', '=', $id)->update(['val' => 0]);
  \DB::table('tablename')->whereIn('id', $request->checked)->update(['val' => $id]);
```

this is one way, but for me it is awful to set all rows to default when I need to set default only not checked ones. The other option is to use foreach, which I don't like in controllers. So question 1 (theoretical and important) - Which takes more resource - huge sql or foreach? Q2 (practical) - how would you solve this problem, considering its Laravel

Comment: I doubt a foreach would perform better, even if you wrap it in a single transaction, you're going to be performing n+1 queries instead of 2.

Comment: Do you want the difference between where and whereIn?

Comment: I assume `where('id', '=', $id)` should be `where('val', '=', $id)` in your first query after reviewing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the inverse of whereIn to your first query.

```
\DB::table('tablename')
    ->whereNotIn('id', $request->checked)
    ->where('val', '=', $id)
    ->update(['val' => 0]);
```

Comment: absolutely. when you know - you know. What do you think about resource saving question? Lately I started caring alot about making code work smart. If anyone knows any articles of how to use less resource and get max result, please share.

Comment: @DimaRashevskiy, my biggest recommendation is to code first and worry about performance later.  There are certainly cases when you need to concern yourself with performance, such as long page loads, but for the most part in web applications, you're dealing with short lived requests, a little extra cpu or memory is going to be cheaper than development time.  Once you're getting millions of hits, start refactoring for performance.

Comment: Of course when you're at work the time is money. But this is a case when I do project for myself and no need to hurry, exploration is what more important. Now I know how to use queries like yours (thanks) and will have less foreach, However, It is better to do it right way before someone looks at it and says that there is better solution

Comment: That's fine if they spot it, that's the whole point of code review and why open source projects can be so beneficial, other coders will always find better ways to do things.  Don't try to be perfect.

Comment: Thanks. What if I have an array of values and I want to insert a row foreach element of an array without actual foreach? is it possible with a query builder? I actually want a row to have 2 values, one is the same and second is array, so like $val1 = 1; $val2 = []; and foreach element of $val2 I need to insert $val1 and $val2[] ?